# How to have multiple citations entries using footcite?

Tags: bibtex, citing

I'm using Biblatex to put my references in footnotes. When I previously used \cite{} to insert references, I could just separate the references with a comma to put in multiple references: \cite{ref1, ref2} would result in
blah blah blah [1,2]; and \cite{c1,c2,c3} would result in [1-3]

I tried this with \autocite, but it doesn't seem to work. Is there an easy way to get this to work?

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose,backend=bibtex, autocite=footnote]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{bibliography.bib}
    @article{c1,
    author = {Neil, Daniel and Liu, Shih-Chii},
    journal = {IEEE Transactions on VLSI Systems},
    title = {{Minitaur, an Event-Driven FPGA-Based Spiking Network Accelerator}},
    year = {2014}
    }

    @book{c2,
      title={Event-Based Neuromorphic Systems},
      author={Liu, Shih-Chii and others},
      year={2015},
      publisher={John Wiley \& Sons}
    }
    @inproceedings{c3,
    title = {Personalized Speech Recognition On Mobile Devices},
    author  = {Ian McGraw and others},
    year  = 2016,
    booktitle = {ICASSP}
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\bibliography{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
I would like the footnote citations~\autocites{c1,c2,c3} to look $like^{1-3}$, but I got 1. 
\end{document}
```

[image: Main Text]
[image: Footnote citation]

Comment: Mhhh, you are just getting citations in a footnote here, you are not using a numeric style. The 1 is the footnote number not the label of any of your citations.

Comment: Anyway to work around this? e.g. footcite?

Comment: Not really, `\autocite` is just `\footcite` here. Why exactly do you want multiple footnote numbers here? Do you have a numeric bibliography? Note that you simply have a footnote with the bibliographic info here.

Comment: I would like to have a numeric bibliography where the citation numbers are displayed like footnote numbers in the main texts. Thanks for the help.

Comment: But how would you then distinguish real footnotes from citations? Would you still want to see the citation in the footnotes like in your example?

Comment: Yes. I was thinking using special symbols for real footnotes, like +, although I don't know how to do this....